# Running multiple applications parallel on single Ingress Controller (e.g. JupyterLab/Elyra + Kubeflow Pipelines UI)

Tags: jupyter-lab, nginx-ingress, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, elyra

I've installed Elyra (which is JupyerLab + some AI centric extensions including a visual editor for creating Kubeflow Pipelines) and KubeFlow Pipelines in parallel on a KIND (Kubernetes In Docker) cluster.

First I've installed Kubeflow Pipelines as documented [here](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/installation/localcluster-deployment/#deploying-kubeflow-pipelines)

> export PIPELINE_VERSION=1.4.1
> kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/cluster-scoped-resources?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"
> kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/applications.app.k8s.io
> kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/manifests/kustomize/env/platform-agnostic-pns?ref=$PIPELINE_VERSION"

Then, I've installed the NGINX Ingress Controller as documented [here](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/ingress/#ingress-nginx)

> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml

Finally, I've installed Elyra/JupyterLab using the following [steps](https://github.com/romeokienzler/DockerizeIT/blob/master/elyra-ai/deploy.sh)

So all UIs I need have the respective services already created:

> k get svc
> NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S) AGE
> elyra-ai     NodePort    10.96.84.31          8888:32111/TCP   94m
> kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1            443/TCP          105m

> k get svc -n kubeflow |grep ml-pipeline-ui
> ml-pipeline-ui                    ClusterIP   10.96.132.233           80/TCP           105m

Therefore I've created an [ingress.yaml](https://gist.github.com/romeokienzler/55579cc2b8ba4769e920716f475d7565) to enable JupyterLab/Elyra to be accessed.

As you can see I'm adding many path entries like login, elyra, git, lsp, lab, kernelspecs, static, ...

So now I'm stuck in two dimensions.

1. I don't want to add path entries for each and every JupyterLab extension I'm installing
2. I can't find a way to also make the Kubeflow Pipelines UI accessible from outside the cluster

The Elyra Pipeline Editor can access the Kubeflow Pipelines Endpoint via ClusterIP though but would be nice have access to the Kubeflow Pipelines UI as well...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use virtual hosts. So either in a DNS or in your /etc/hosts file add for example:

> 127.0.0.1 elyra.local.host
> 127.0.0.1 kubeflow.local.host

Then the two service.yaml become straightforward, for Elyra/JupyteLab:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: elyra-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "elyra.local.host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: elyra-ai
            port:
              number: 8888
```

For Kubeflow Pipelines:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: kfp-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "kubeflow.local.host"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ml-pipeline-ui
            port:
              number: 80
```